How is Intention-to-Treat treatment effect(ITT) different from Average Treatment Effect(ATE)?
I've learned that $ATE = [Y(1)-Y(0)]$ and $ATT = [Y(1)-Y(0)|A=1]$.
The difference is whether or not you limit the population of interest to the treated people.
I've also learned that when there is non-compliance/non-adherence, intent-to-treat(ITT) ignores this and only compares the groups who were randomized to take the treatment vs who weren't. Per-protocol treatment effect on the other hand only looks at who ended up taking the treatment vs who didn't.
What are the differences between these concepts?
At first, I posted this question because I thought ITT is the same as ATE and wanted to know the formulas for ITT and per-protocol effect
Now that I think about it, ATE and ATT is an "estimand".
ITT is comparing people who were randomized to take the treatment vs who weren't, so it's not an "estimand", but rather "how you estimate" ATE. Is this correct?
